# How do I CSS the "fusion" of two round border boxes

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to achieve something like this. Of course the text in both sections can vary in length which would stretch the "structure", maintaining some padding on the sides, top/bottom.

I know about `border-radius`, it's just that the two elements together isn't clear to me how to achieve.

Comment: What you've tried so far??

Comment: I have two border-radius boxes close to each other on the same line...both styled for the contrast backgrounds you see -- I just need to "move them together" a bit. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Style them the same, give them some good left/right padding, then every item after the first, give it a negative left margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to style an outer and an inner element.

```css
.out-el{
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius:15px;
  padding:8px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.in-el{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
  padding:8px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:-8px;
  border-radius:14px;
  margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out-el">
 <span>THE KEY</span>
 <span class="in-el">THIS IS THE VALUE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!